# Compare 2 large files, with powershell or other means?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compare 2 very large files, both files got over 9 million words in them and are around 340mb each.

I have also tried programs like Beyond compare, and a few others. The programs will compare the 2 files, but when I try to save the file it crashes.

When I try to use Powershell, I can't seem to get it working:

```
$folder1 = Get-Content C:\Newfolder\ParentGUID.txt
$folder2 = Get-Content C:\Newfolder\GUID.txt

Compare-Object $folder1 $folder2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent 

$folder1 = Get-Content C:\Newfolder\ParentGUID.txt | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
$folder2 = Get-Content C:\Newfolder\GUID.txt | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }

Compare-Object $folder1 $folder2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent

out-file c:\Newfolder\myfolder.txt
```

And

```
$Acer   = Import-Csv -Path C:\Newfolder\GUID.txt
$SAS    = Import-Csv -Path C:\Newfolder\ParentGUID.txt
$Header = $Acer | Get-Member | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Acer -DifferenceObject $SAS -Property 'Unique ID' -PassThru | Select-Object -Property $Header |
Export-Csv -Path C:\Newfolder\NewStudents.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Are you sure PowerShell is the correct tool for this? I would look at `fc`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc

Comment: Does your powershell work with small files? It doesn't look like you're actually outputting anything to the file...